# Make `TextField` look active without it having a default value

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was wondering how I would go about making a `TextField` always look active:
[image]

Without it actually having a default value like the `TextField` in the screenshot does

My current code for the `TextField` in the screenshot is:

```
TextField(
    value = npcId.toString(),
    onValueChange = { npcId = it.toInt() },
    label = { Text("Npc id") },
    enabled = true
)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it in the state where its label is small and hovering over where you enter text, regardless of whether it is the in-focus view?

Comment: Yeah basically, in the screenshot its not in-focus, it just has a default value. I just want it to display like that without needing a default value @Tenfour04

Comment: Do you mean you need the TextField to be always "focused on"?

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you do not want the default value to display in the TextField.
If the default value is -1 in this case, the following should work:

```
TextField(
    value = if (npcID == -1) "" else npcId.toString(),
    onValueChange = { npcId = it.toInt() },
    label = { Text("Npc id") },
    enabled = true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeded with this way.It is here source code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.focusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.onFocusChanged
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalTextInputService
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MainScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            AutoFocusingText()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AutoFocusingText() {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val inputService = LocalTextInputService.current
    val focus = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val text = remember { mutableStateOf("-1")}

    TextField(
        value = if (text.value == "-1") "" else text.value,
        onValueChange = {
            text.value = it
        },
        label = { Text("Npc id") },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .onFocusChanged {
                if (focus.value != it.isFocused) {
                    focus.value = it.isFocused
                    if (!it.isFocused) {
                        inputService?.hideSoftwareKeyboard()
                    }
                }
            }
    )

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        delay(100)
        inputService?.showSoftwareKeyboard()
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}

@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MainScreen()
}
```